# como restringir dias y horas por php a un input type="datetime-local"?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, php5

Estoy creando un registro de espacios para una residencia, donde solo 4 usuarios puedan reservar el mismo lugar (piscina, parque, cancha etc...) pero debe de estar entre unas horas especificas, no se si estoy colocando el codigo bien y aparte a eso cuando ya existan 4 reservas, al usuario siguiente debe mostrarle un mensaje donde diga "aforo lleno" alguien puede ayudarme?? adjunto mi codigo... no se como contruir esa parte del codigo...  creo que el `date_default_timezone_set("America/Venezuela");` no lo esta reconociendo el codigo esta incompleto èn el primero `else if` de antemano muchas gracias!!

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn_reserva']))
{
    $fecha           = $_REQUEST['fecha']; 
    $cantidadp       = $_REQUEST['selPersonas'];
    $espacio         = $_REQUEST['selam'];  
    $name            = $_REQUEST['txt_nom'];        
    $last_name       = $_REQUEST['txt_apel'];   
    $hora_s          = $_REQUEST['fecha'];
    $fecha_s         = $_REQUEST['fecha'];
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Venezuela");
    if(empty($fecha)){
        $errorMsg[]="Ingrese fecha";
    }
    
    else if (strlem($fecha) $hora_s && $fecha_s >= 7:00 am && $hora_s && $fecha_s <= 21:00 pm ){
        $errorMsg[]= "Horario no disponible";
    } else if (strlem ($fecha) )


    else if (empty($cantidadp)){
        $errorMsg[]="Ingrese cantidad de personas";
    }
    else if (empty($name)){
        $errorMsg[]="Ingrese su nombre";
    }
    else if (empty($last_name)){
        $errorMsg[]="Ingrese su apellido";
    }
    else
    {
```

Comment: Porque usas strlen en la fecha? segun la documentacion de php strlen — Obtiene la longitud de un string, porque usas eso en la fecha? si estas obteniendo una fecha tipo 2021-02-03 te va a devolver el total de caracteres

Comment: Ademas estas usando elsif, eso significa que si la primera condicion no se cumple arroja la siguiente, y por tu codigo se entiende=  si fecha esta vacia por favor coloca una fecha, si no esta vacio verifica si la fecha y la hora son mayor o igual de las 7:00 am o si es menor o igual a las 21:00 pm, si eso se cumple indica que no hay cupo, y etc.. asi que podrias decir desde que hora esta abierto?

Comment: con strlen lo habia visto en internet, pero no me funcionaba, se supone que debe estar abierto desde las 7:00 de la mañana hasta las 21:00 , y no deben de haber mas de 4 reservas por area a la misma hora.

Comment: Pues no, bastaria obtener la fecha con ```setlocale(LC_ALL, 'America/TUCIUDAD');
  echo $fecha = date('g:i');``` con ese echo veras que te mostrara la hora actual